# Does anyone say that mind/brain type identity theory is just vacuous without scientific evidence that some part brain state is always the exact same?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-mind, identity, cognitive-sciences

Does anyone say that mind/brain type identity theory is just vacuous without scientific evidence that some part brain state is always the exact same experience? I think that's what type identity amounts so, and I was wondering if I could just shrug without any evidence that scientists will ever demonstrate those identities, besides belief in scientific progress.

Comment: What experience do you think that one "same experience" is?

Comment: Mind-brain identity is a metaphysical theory, not scientific. Scientists will never demonstrate this identity since they cannot demonstrate the existence of mind. Category-errors of this kind make philosophy of mind a muddle.

Comment: There is something wrong with the phrasing in "some part brain state is always the exact same experience". Since Putnam's criticisms in 1970-s [type identity physicalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_physicalism) was largely abandoned.